# Resize images to multiple sizes using imagemagick

Tags: imagemagick

I have a directory that contains many subdirectories. Each subdirectory contains many .jpg files. I am looking for an ImageMagick command that will:

1. Resize each .jpg to multiple, specific sizes (preserving aspect ratio)
2. Rename each .jpg
3. Delete the original .jpg

For example, if I have a directory that contains a single `image.jpg` with size 1505x721, after running the command the directory would now contain the following:

`image-small.jpg` with width 220

`image-medium.jpg` with height 324

`image-large.jpg` with width 1024

I assume I need to use the `mogrify` command, but I can't figure out how to output multiple files at a time recursively.

Answer (score 0):

In Imagemagick, you cannot use mogrify to output more than one image for each input. You would have to write a script loop over each directory or collection of directories. For each image in the directory, you would process to write multiple output images.

For any one image, you can use convert (Imagemagick 6) or magick (Imagemagick 7) as follows (in Unix Syntax):

```
convert input.jpg -write mpr:img +delete \
\( mpr:img -resize 220x +write input_220w.jpg \) \
\( mpr:img -resize x324 +write input_324h.jpg \) \
\( mpr:img -resize 1024x +write input_1024w.jpg \) \
null:
```

In Windows syntax, this would be:

```
convert input.jpg -write mpr:img +delete ^
( mpr:img -resize 220x +write input_220w.jpg ) ^
( mpr:img -resize x324 +write input_324h.jpg ) ^
( mpr:img -resize 1024x +write input_1024w.jpg ) ^
null:
```